# How to write a MySQL query to generate a new table by selecting some values from it?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named orthologygen:

```
ko, gene
ko:1, has:1
ko:2, has:2
ko:3, has:3
ko:4, pps:4
ko:4, pps:5
ko:3, rno:3
ko:3, rno:4
ko:2, rno:6
ko:4, rno:7
```

and I want to generate a new table using MySQL like this:

```
has,rno
has:1, rno:3
has:2, rno:4
has:3, rno:6
```

My current version of this query is like this:

```
select t1.hsa, t2.rno 
from
(SELECT @n := @n + 1 as id, o1.gene as hsa FROM orthologygen o1, (select @n := 0) m where gene like "hsa%") t1
join  
(SELECT @n := @n + 1 as id, o2.gene as rno FROM orthologygen o2, (select @n := 0) m where gene like "rno%") t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

However, it returns empty, do you know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Please explain the logic that transforms the original data to the desired result set.

Comment: It's not just `hsa` vs `has` is it?

Comment: no, hsa is just a prefix, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see.  You need different variables and to initialize them:

```
select h.hsa, r.rno 
from (select (@nh := @nh + 1) as id, o1.gene as hsa 
      from orthologygen o1 cross join
           (select @nh := 0) m
      where gene like 'hsa%'
     ) h join  
     (select (@nr := @nr + 1) as id, o2.gene as rno 
      from orthologygen o2 cross join
           (select @nr := 0) m
      where gene like 'rno%'
     ) r
     on r.id = h.id
```

Comment: fantastic! it works! could you please tell me more about why my way the variables do not work?

Comment: @JudahFlynn . . . You have only one variable in the question.  I think the initialization happens twice.  Then the values produced are just sequential -- they don't start over for each subquery.

Comment: so this means when the query has been submitted to execute, my variable @n is just initialed twice at first place, then it goes to next step? Could you please point me some books to explain the order of execution in SQL, I am confused now

Comment: @JudahFlynn . . . You can read the MySQL documentation, but this is highly specific and not described in the documentation.  Just use a variable for only one thing in a query.

Comment: thanks, I need to go back to refresh my memory about this!